# Violin - Best way to treat rosin build up on the strings?

Tags: violin, maintenance

Recently, my violin's sound wasn't coming very well. I searched it on Google, and found out it was because of rosin build up on my strings, a common case. What is the best way to treat rosin build up on the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rosin can be easily and safely cleaned from strings with isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol.  Put a bit on a rag and wipe the strings with it.  Be very careful not to drip any alcohol on the instrument, though.

Comment: Perhaps hold the instrument upside-down, so it doesn't drip alcohol onto the instrument.